# mDNSResponder missing

Tags: macos, printing, bonjour, dns

I am on Yosemite since today and am trying to connect to network printers, but System Preferences doesn't show any. The printers use Bonjour and I read that the associated process is mDNSresponder. Checking Activity Monitor I see it is not running. Googling how to manually restart it reveals tips such as these.

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist
```

However, the `.plist` file does not exist, neither does `/usr/sbin/mDNSResponder`.

The thing is that the printer problem existed even before I upgraded from 10.7.5 to 10.10, so I cannot judge whether this is a Yosemite issue or not, or wether the mDNSResponder stuff is even the source. I also don't know if I had the files before (although at some point I must have).

How do I enable Bonjour on Yosemite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mDNSResponder` was replaced by `DiscoveryUtil` in Yosemite. So Bonjour is still enabled. According to this [Apple-kb article](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH18609) you might have to download updated printer drivers from Apple or the original manufacturer or re-add your printer with a different set up.
If you still have problems discovering your printer an [Apple-discussion-thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6607871) might help:  unblock discoveryd in the firewall preferences and an immediate reboot...

Comment: I see. Do you know how to detect whether Bonjour is running on  10.10? i.e., what process do I look for?

Comment: discoveryd and discoveryd_helper. 'sudo discoveryutil help' in Terminal gives a plethora of possible commands